# Cannot add MVVM Light libraries through NuGet

Tags: nuget, mvvm-light

I'm trying to add MVVM Light to an existing project through NuGet but I get this error message:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmLightLibs (≥ 4.2.30.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'CommonServiceLocator (≥ 1.2)'.
Successfully installed 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmLightLibs 4.3.31.1'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmLight 4.2.30.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'CommonServiceLocator 1.2'. You are
trying to install this package into a project that targets
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client', but the package
does not contain any assembly references that are compatible
with that framework. For more information, contact the package
author.
```

I've tried retargeting my project to .NET framework 4.0, 4.0 client profile, and 4.5. Any ideas? I wasn't having this issue as recently as two weeks ago.

Answer (score 12):

Had the same Problem today. Try to install the newest Version of Nuget in your Visual Studio Addins first !

Comment: this solved it for me.  to install the latest nuget, go into the Visual Studio Tools Menu.  Go to extensions and updates.  Go to installed packages and look for NuGet.  Click Update to get the latest NuGet functionality. Restart Visual Studio.  Go to the PM console and type:

install-package MVVMLightLibs

Comment: Yes, Updating the NuGet Package Manager solved my same problem

Answer (score 2):

I am able to install while targeting 4.5 and using Nuget for "MVVM Light Libraries only"

Does installing https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/1.2.0 first avoid the issue for you?

Comment: Thanks, I did the same thing and was able to get MVVMLight installed, however I do need CommonServiceLocator because it adds support for Autofac which is my preferred IoC container. Installing CommonServiceLocator separately still returns the same error message.

Comment: Is it clashing with Autofac, and failing to uninstall the Autofac version of CommonServiceLocator? It is lame, but sometimes I have resorted to creating a new project with the problem parts working, then copying the old code in manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Updated Visual Studio 2012 to Update 4, tried again and it worked perfectly. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your project is targeting .NET 4.0 while you are installing library witch are not compatible to the targeted version.

Please find appropriate version of library and install them